# How to get the SAMLResponse in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, saml

I'm using Fiddler to trace my single sign on between my Shibboleth Service Provider and a customer's Identity Provider.

I'm successfully getting redirected to the IdP's login page, and I'm successfully able to login to the Idp's site.  It's properly redirecting the browser back to the page I originally tried to access, but I don't see how to get at the SAML (which has the information I need to authorize the user into my web app).

I looped through the HTTP parameters and didn't see anything that had the attribute information of my customer's IdP.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4.  Here's what I see in Fiddler:

SAMLResponse=PHNhbWxwOlJlc3Bvb.....&RelayState=ss:mem:234e27f....

I feel like I'm really close and there's just one small thing I'm missing.

**EDIT - I see the SAMLResponse coming back in Fiddler... just not sure how to get at it in ASP.NET.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler has a text wizard to transform the SAML response.

First you highlight the text inside the SAML response. For example: name="SAMLResponse" value="`PHNhbXJ0aW9uPjwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U`" />

Then you paste it (everything between the double-quotes) into the Text Wizard (found with control-e) with `From Base64` as your transformation. That should display the SAML response in human-readable form.

Comment: Ok, this totally worked.  I had to URL decode it first.  However, how can I get at this exact piece of information via my ASP.NET MVC controller? It's definitely coming back as expected, so I just need to figure out how I can access it.  I'm really close here.

Comment: Assuming what's in Fiddler is what you expect, I just go through the SAML response field-by-field looking for the data I need.

Comment: Right, but when you say "go through the SAML response".  Where does this exist? Is this the request content? I'm not seeing it in the headers.

Comment: It's not in the header it's in the POST data.

Comment: Gotcha... I'm having a hard time getting in in ASP.NET.  It sounds like I'm 95% the way there.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this question.  Next I need to figure out how to pass the SAML through to my webapp.

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm facing similar situation. Could you please post the code that you used to handle the SAML token in your controller? Thanks